# Error while running ng server about Require Stack - Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, npm-install, angular9

When i run ng serve --open in my project it shows

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\ALEXAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-mrsQtL\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

this is my ng --version:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.0
Node: 12.15.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.0
... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.901.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            9.1.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      9.1.0 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                    <error>
@angular/compiler-cli           <error>
@angular/language-service       <error>
@schematics/angular             9.1.0 (cli-only)
@schematics/update              0.901.0 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.5.4
typescript                      <error>
```

I think the problem is with my npm install -g @angular/cli.
it doesnt download dev dependencies of angular

Pls, i tried to fix for days

Answer (score 0):

***First Suggestion***

npm installations sometimes do not complete successfully, please delete the `node_modules` folder and reinstall via `npm install`:

```
rm -rf node_modules 
npm cache clean 
npm install
```

---

***Second Suggestion*** 
you can manually install all missing packages:

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli@latest
npm install @angular/language-service@latest
npm install @angular/cli@latest
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular 
npm install -g typescript@latest
```